# Weedo Tina2/Monoprice Cadet auto bed leveling: Sensor not moving down to touch the print bed

Tags: bed-leveling, z-axis

So I bought this printer three days ago as a way to dip my toes into the 3D printing world, and it was working great at first. But at some point, the ABL procedure started behaving oddly: Instead of moving down to touch each corner of the printing bed, it's now only doing so for one corner, then moving to the next, but instead of going down, it goes up. It then continues to the third corner, stops, and moves up again. After that, it returns back to home position. The result is that the extruder hovers way above where it's supposed to be --or alternatively bumps into the printing bed when it's near the origin corner-- thinking it's adjusting for some nonexistent slant, dripping filament all over the place.

The gantry itself is totally level, and I can't see any mechanical faults. As far as I can tell, there's no way to manually level the bed, the only option is to use ABL.

I found out that the Monoprice Cadet printer is the exact same one as the Tina2, so if anyone has experience with that printer in particular, it'll apply here too.

Comment: This question is attracting a lot of "Me too" answers lately (apparently becomming a common issue), enough for the community bot to automatically protect the question from low rep. users to answer the question. If you (@stale_mud)) have found an answer by now, please add this yourself, if impossible to answer yourself as in prohibited by the protection, please reply to this comment using my name with an @ in front, I can unprotect the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer from [an answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/lz4c9l/comment/gr9v9pb/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on [Reddit - Monoprice Cadet auto-leveling question](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/lz4c9l/monoprice_cadet_autoleveling_question/), for those who stumble upon this question:

> Then I tried their text chat support and the response was basically:
>
> "It is a bad level sensor, which we've never heard of happening to a 3 month old printer and is very rare in general. You are under warranty so here's a preprinted return shipping label, and we'll send you a new printer once we receive your busted one."

---

*From the many "me too" answers, this appears to be a genuine issue rather than a "one-off" issue...*

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manufacturer's page for the Weedo Tina 2](http://www.weedo.ltd/product-detail/tina2/), the bed sensor for the ABL is magnetic -- which means that if you've removed the magnetic build surface you likely have removed the printer's ability to sense the bed height.  You most likely need to replace the worn out magnetic build surface for the (mandatory) ABL to work.

Weedo ought to sell replacements for a part that wears out, but if not, you can buy one made for the Ender 3 (and cut it down to fit) on Amazon (very reasonably priced, too) and have it in your hands in a couple days, though I have no way to know the original didn't have specific poles in particular locations on the sheet.  You'll likely need to remove the base sheet from the Tina 2, if there is one, so as to follow the instructions on the Creality and ensure the upper, removable, flexible sheet actually sticks to the adhesive-backed lower sheet.

Comment: The magnetic build surface is still there: I only removed the adhesive paper on top of it, and the magnetic surface itself is fine, it's only three days old as well.

Comment: For the magnetic build surface I'm familiar with (on my Ender 3) the texture layer isn't separable from the upper of the two magnetic sheets, and I don't know that I could print on it without the textured surface, anyway.